# Is there any method to reuse the node modules in react?

Tags: reactjs

Since I am learning it takes me a lot of time to create multiple react apps? Is there any option to reuse the react app for different projects?

Comment: What do you mean by creating multiple react apps ? If you're only doing testing, can't you create newer components inside the same project and test them ? Or you can just copy the project content to another folder and work on it if it's really difficult to download the node modules again and again.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was taking too much time to create new app all the time